# Upload base64 image to server

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swift4

I'm using `Alamofire` and `swiftyJson` I want to upload image to server as base64 , I used this code to upload my image

```
class func uploadMultipleAdvertisementImage(photos: UIImage, completion: @escaping (_ error: Error?, _ sucess: Bool, _ image_id: Int)-> Void) {

let url = URLs.uploadImages

var images = [Data]()
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (form: MultipartFormData) in



   if let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photos , 0.5) {
        form.append(data, withName: "images", fileName: "photo.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
    }

}, usingThreshold: SessionManager.multipartFormDataEncodingMemoryThreshold, to: url, method: .post, headers: nil) { (result: SessionManager.MultipartFormDataEncodingResult) in

    switch result {
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
        completion(error, false, 0)

    case .success(request: let upload, streamingFromDisk: _, streamFileURL: _):

        upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress: Progress) in
            print(progress)
        })
            .responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response: DataResponse<Any>) in

                switch response.result
                {
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                    completion(error, false, 0)

                case .success(let value):
                    let json = JSON(value)
                    print(json)
                    if(json["msg"] == "image uploaded successfully") {
                        let image_id = json["image_id"].int ?? 0
                        print("hiiiiiiiiii", image_id)
                        completion(nil, true, image_id)
                    }
                }

            })
    }

 }
}
```

but i want to upload it as base 64, what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the UIImage to a format your website can read, e.g. jpeg before encoding it in base 64.

```
let jpegCompressionQuality: CGFloat = 0.9 // Set this to whatever suits your purpose
if let base64String = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage, jpegCompressionQuality)?.base64EncodedString() {
    // Upload base64String to your database
}
```

Refer to the Apple documentation for [UIImageJPEGRepresentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/1624115-uiimagejpegrepresentation) and [Data](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data/2142853-base64encodedstring)

Comment: You might consider using `base64EncodedData() ` instead so that you do not need the extra String to Data conversion.

Comment: multipart can not appen string!

Answer (score 0):

`Data` has a function to return a base64 representation of itself as another `Data`. No need to convert to `String` and back.

Take a look at the docs for `Data.base64EncodedData()`

```
if let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photos, 0.5)?.base64EncodedData() {
    form.append(data, withName: "images", fileName: "photo.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert image to base64 like this

```
let encodingOptions = NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0)
let encodedImageData = pickedImage.base64EncodedString(options: encodingOptions)
```

then use encodedImageData as a parameter in your request